# JavaのコードをKotlinのコードに置き換えたい

Tags: java, kotlin

以下に示したコードの様にJavaをKotlinで置き換えてみましたが、コメントアウトを外すとコンパイルエラーになります。

Javaの方が長いので、おそらくJava風？なKotlinのコードになってしまっているかもしれませんが、どこに原因があると思われますでしょうか？

---

**元のJavaコード**

```
class Super {
   static String x = "Super : x";
   String y = "Super : y";
   static void methodA() {
       System.out.println("Super : methodA()");
   }
   void methodB() {
       System.out.println("Super methodB()");
   }
}
class Sub extends Super {
   static String x = "Sub : x";
   String y = "Sub : y";
   static void methodA() {
       System.out.println("Sub : methodA()");
   }
   void methodB() {
       System.out.println("Sub : methodB()");
   }
}
class Sample {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
        Super obj = new Sub();
        System.out.println(obj.x);
        System.out.println(obj.y);
        obj.methodA();
        obj.methodB();
   }
}
```

**Kotlinで置き換えたコード**

```
open class Super {
     open val y: String = "Super : y"

     companion object {
          val x: String = "Super : x"

          fun methodA() {
                println("Super : methodA()")
          }
     }

     open fun methodB() {
           println("Super : methodB()")
     }
}
class Sub : Super() {
      override val y: String = "Sub : y"

      companion object {
           val x: String = "Sub : x"

           fun methodA() {
                 println("Sub : methodA()")
           }
      }

      override fun methodB() {
            println("Sub : methodB()")
      }
}
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
       val obj: Super = Sub()
       //println(obj.x)
       println(obj.y)
       //obj.methodA()
       obj.methodB()
}
```

Comment: ツールで試してみるとか。[JavaファイルからKotlinファイルへの変換](https://pleiades.io/help/idea/converting-a-java-file-to-kotlin-file.html)

Comment: ありがとうございます！実はJavaで書いたものをIntelliJで変換したみたのですが、やはりそのまますぐ動く状態に変換というわけにはいかず、エラーがどこかしこにいっぱい出まして、探りながら直そうにもわかりませんでした…。なので地力でやってみた次第です。まずクラスブロックがあるのに変数の重複がダメとか（オーバーライドを強制される）、変換したコードも明らかにJavaより記述量増えてませんか？みたいな感じで、JavaにできてKotlinにできないこともあるのでしょうか？

Comment: 済みません。検索結果を紹介しただけなので詳しいことは判りません。手作業だとこんな記事があります。[JavaからKotlinに変換する7つのテクニック Kotlinらしさを生かした簡潔なコードに置き換えよう](https://employment.en-japan.com/engineerhub/entry/2019/05/14/103000), あと古い記事がこのあたり [Convert Java to Kotlin](https://qiita.com/ssuzaki/items/8a550fca6775c1e6e147), [毎日Kotlin Day2. Java to Kotlin conversion（JavaをKotlinに変換）](https://dev.classmethod.jp/smartphone/kotlin-everyday-2/)

Comment: ありがとうございます！じっくり読ませて頂きます！

Answer (score 1):

そもそも元のJavaコードが「こんなコードを書くと一見奇妙な結果が出る」書き方の例になっています。

- 隠蔽フィールドの宣言

  Javaでは、サブクラス側のフィールドは親クラス側のフィールドを隠すような別フィールドになる。コンパイラは「コンパイル時に見えている側」のフィールドを使う。
- `static`メンバーのインスタンスからの呼び出し

  Javaではコンパイル時に決まる型を元にしてどのクラスの`static`メンバーを使うか決められる。

いずれも現在のJavaコンパイラでは警告が出るはずです。これらの警告を無視しないようにしましょう。

---

Kotlinでは、そのような誤用を防ぐため、そもそも同様のことは出来ないようになっています。

- フィールドを直接宣言できない

  Kotlinのプロパティ宣言はJavaで言うと、フィールドとgetterとsetterをまとめて宣言しているようなものです。従って、メソッドと同様にオーバライドもでき、メソッドのオーバライドと同様の挙動になります。
- `static`なメンバーは定義できない

  Kotlinの`companion`は「特定のクラスに結びついた別オブジェクトのプロパティやメソッド」を宣言するためのものです。`static`の代替とみなされていますが、Javaの`static`と完全に同じ動作をするわけではなく、インスタンスを通じては呼び出せません。

無理やりコンパイルが通るように書くと、こんな感じになるでしょう。

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
       val obj: Super = Sub()
       println(Super.x)
       println(obj.y)
       Sub.methodA()
       obj.methodB()
}
```

上記のように`Super`か`Sub`を明示しないと呼び出せないので、Javaのように「`Sub`側のプロパティやメソッドが参照されると思ったら`Super`の方だった」なんてことは起こりません。

---

KotlinはJavaと相互運用できるよう考えられていますが、「文法が違うだけでJavaと全く同じ」なのではありません。ご質問にあるJavaコードのように「時に期待と異なる一見奇妙な結果が出る」ようなコードの挙動を完全に再現することは出来ません。

Comment: ありがとうございます！確かに、Javaのコードの方が実用的にはまどろっこしいコードですよね。Goldの教科書をKotlinに置き換えていて、ふと、「参照型はスーパータイプ、クラス型はサブタイプ」のやり方や、継承関係におけることで認識が正しいのか気になりました。警告はありませんでしたが、なんでもそのまま置き換えられるものではないということは勉強になりました！ありがとうございます！

Comment: @user31658 さん、コメントありがとうございます。警告については環境にもよるのに、必ず表示されるかのように書いたのは乱暴すぎましたね、失礼しました。ご質問へのコメントで示されたように、Javaの置き換えではなく、Kotlinらしいコーディングをするのが重要なのだろうと思います。私もKotlinについては学習中の身で、今回のような、知識のリフレッシュに役立つ質問は大変助かります。ありがとうございました。